# divs height in % is not working in ie

Tags: css, asp.net

I am creating a web page ; where i would like to show 4 predefined divs on treeview checkbox selection.
Divs are showing perfectly fine in chrome and mozilla Firefox but the height in % is not working in Internet Explorer 9 and IE11.

I am setting the divs height and width in %. Divs width in % is working but height is not.
Please help me.

```
 for (var y = 1; y <= value; y++)
{
 var player_Parent=$('[id$=divView_' + y + ']');
 append_Player(noOfPlayers, player_Parent); 
}
function append_Player(no_of_Players, player_Parent_iOS)
{ 
  if (no_of_Players == 1)
  { $(player_Parent_iOS).attr('class','single'); }
  else if (no_of_Players == 2) 
 { $(player_Parent_iOS).attr('class', 'double'); } 
}
```

CSS is as following..

```
 .single 
  {
     height:100%; width:100%; display:block; border-width:thin;
  }
 .double
  {
    height:100%; width:50%; border-width:thin;  border-style:solid;
   }
```

Divs are as follows:

```
 <div id="divView_1" hascombo="false" isloaded="false" onclick="click(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" 
                    style="position:relative; background-color:#99D9EA; float: left; display: block;">
                    <div id="container_1" style="background-color:Yellow; width: 100%;   height: 100%; position:relative;float: right; background-color: transparent;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divView_2" hascombo="false" isloaded="false"  onclick="click(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" style="background-color:#99D9EA; top:-100%; position:relative;  display: block;float: right;">
                    <div id="container_2" style="background-color:Yellow; width: 100%;   height: 100%; float: right; position:relative; background-color: transparent;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divView_3" hascombo="false" isloaded="false" onclick="click(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" style="background-color:#99D9EA;  position:relative;display:block; float:left;">
                    <div id="container_3" style="background-color:Yellow; width: 100%;   height: 100%; position:relative;float: left; background-color: transparent;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divView_4" hascombo="false" isloaded="false" onclick="click(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" style="background-color:#99D9EA;  position:relative; display: block;float: right;">
                    <div id="container_4" style="background-color:Yellow; width: 100%;   height: 100%;position:relative; float: right; background-color: transparent;">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

without the rest of the code it is all guesswork. 
* did you give 100% height to the parent?
* did you give height 100% to body and html (in case all design is responsive)?
* i can see the divView_1 style top property is missing semicolon.

Need more details on the rest of the code.

Comment: do you have a working demo so i can see the problem?